# Is it possible in snowflake to write a query that lists the columns that have all null values?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-profiling

In snowsight within snowflake, you can profile tables and see the % of null values in the UI, but is there an easy way to query for this data or export it from the UI? I just need to create a new table off a table with 1k+, but exclude columns that only have null vaules?

Input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TAB(Q INT, X INT, Y INT, Z INT)
AS
SELECT NULL, 0041X00002OEkZ5QAL,2, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 2, NULL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Snowpark to remove all-nullable columns:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, count

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    # input
    df = session.table('PUBLIC.TAB')

    # columns with all nulls
    dropcols = [c for c in df.columns if df.agg(count(col(c))).collect()[0][0]==0]

    # save as new table without nulls columns
    df.drop(dropcols).write.save_as_table('PUBLIC.TAB_WITHOUT_NULL',mode='overwrite')
            
    return 'Success'
```

For input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TAB(Q INT, X INT, Y INT, Z INT)
AS
SELECT NULL, 1,2, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 3, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 2, NULL;

SELECT * FROM TAB;
/*
Q   X   Y   Z
    1   2   
        
    3       
        2   
*/
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB_WITHOUT_NULL;
/*
X   Y
1   2
    
3   
    2
*/
```

---

Related:

- [Removing columns with all 0s using SQL/ Snowpark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989385/5070879)
- [Snowflake count nulls in all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932559/5070879)

Comment: any chance I can have the code written directly in snowflake ui, don't want to have to accessing the api for secruity, this is a quick analysis as well. 

ie the python udf or javascript? Or just plain sql?

Comment: @0004 Yes, you could easily Snowsight UI to run it directly [Snowflake - invoking Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75899802/5070879) and if you parametrize src/target table name and hit deploy button it will create a Python stored procedure

Comment: The code you shared removes columns that have values, any idea why? 

For instance, it removed an id column that had values such as 0041X00002OEkZ5QAL

Comment: @0004 Please share a sample data in form of `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO`  to replicate this scenario- I cannot reproduce it - https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUkpF.png. The code is performing COUNT(col) and if all values are NULL in that column it returns 0, therefore indicating that column should be skipped from the dataframe.

Comment: the table has 300 columns, so it was hard -- but I made an edit to yours

Comment: @0004 Please provide data type as well as the value "0041X00002OEkZ5QAL" is most likely not an INT

Comment: it is a VARCHAR(16777216)


Each column in the table will vary in any of the data types available outside of variant

Comment: @0004 I have tried the example you provided and the column was NOT removed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqmLZ.png - As a debug I suggest to comment out "# save as new table without nulls columns" part , `return dropcols` array and manually compare against your table.

Comment: I will look back into, thank you

Comment: Yea, it worked you are right thx again! 

Got another one if your looking for points!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76057823/calculating-of-column-values-that-are-null-in-snowsight-pands-getting-error