# Calculating % of column values that are Null in snowsight/pands -- getting error

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to identify what columns have more than 90% of their values as Null and then remove them from the table, and really just return a list or empty table of all the columns did not get removed. I have the code below (writing in snowpark/snowflake):

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, count

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    # Your code goes here, inside the "main" handler.
    tableName = 'schema.table'
    df = session.table(tableName)
    null_percentages = df.isnull().mean()

    # Identify columns with over 90% null values
    null_cols = null_percentages[null_percentages > 0.9].index.tolist()
```

error:

```
00357 (P0000): Python Interpreter Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_udf_code.py", line 23, in main
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/81026afe07d5ccb2100e9e480aaccb104b6644cbe92cb335909de3e6bad43727/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/snowpark/dataframe.py", line 884, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Table object has no attribute isnull
 in function PYTHON_WORKSHEET with handler main
```

Sample input if you want to try locally in snowflake and name it schema.table, it will read in to create the df:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TAB(Q INT, X INT, Y INT, Z INT)
AS
SELECT NULL, 0041X00002OEkZ5QAL,2, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, 2, NULL;
```

Comment: What would be your input for pandas? is `df` really a DataFrame?

Comment: that table that I provided the sql for. so you run that sql in snowflake to create a table and read that table in as a df

Answer (score 0):

```
null_percentages = df.isnull().mean()
```

In this code line, you are trying to invoke function isnull() for 'TABLE' type. But this function isnull() is not available for 'TABLE', its for the 'COLUMN' type.

So you have to change to

```
null_percentages = df.col("Q").isnull().mean()
```